# Understanding Linker Version Scripts

Tags: c, linker

I am trying to understand version script that is being used for resolving duplicate symbol problem.

I have created a main_demo.c file with the following content

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern void fun1_std(void);
extern void fun1_linux(void);


int main ()
{
    fun1_linux(); //defined under libfun1_linux.c
    fun1_std();   //defined under libfun2_std.c
    return 0;
}
```

Content of libfun1_std.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern void fun (void);
void fun1_std()

{
    fun();  
}
```

Content of libfun1_linux.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern void fun (void);
void fun1_linux()

{
    fun();
}
```

Now , I have created shared object for both the above files (which are calling fun()) named as libfun1_std.so and libfun1_linux.so respectively. The function "fun()" is defined under two shared objects that looks like the following:

```
//library name ==> libfun2_linux.so 
#include <stdio.h>

void fun()
{
    printf("In fun of libfun2_linux\n");
    //Similarly libfun2_std.so is printing "In fun of libfun2_std" 
}
```

My expectation is that symbol "fun" used in libfun1_linux.so is resolved by libfun2_linux.so and similarly "fun" used in libfun2_std.so is resolved by libfun2_std.so

As we can see if we create a executable/process by linking the main program with all the above shared libraries, process will get duplicate symbol in it's address space i.e, fun(). SO the output look like this:

```
In fun of libfun2_std

In fun of libfun2_std
```

To resolve this I have created a version script that will rename the symbol. 
Content of version script:

```
LIBFUN2_STD_1.0 {
global: *; //i.e, every symbol is global
};
```

and compiled libfun2_std.so with this version script. 
Let's see the symbol again:-

```
 $ readelf -a libfun2_std.so | grep fun
13: 0000000000000735    18 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fun@@LIBFUN2_STD_1.0
35: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS libfun2_std.c
48: 0000000000000735    18 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fun
000000: Rev: 1  Flags: BASE   Index: 1  Cnt: 1  Name: libfun2_std.so
```

Also the content of caller library

```
nm libfun1_std.so | grep fun
0000000000000705 T fun1_std
                 U fun@@LIBFUN2_STD_1.0.
```

So now it seems that we have resolved the duplicate symbol. Let's create the main executable again

```
gcc -Wall -o main_demo main_demo.c -lfun1_std -lfun2_std -lfun1_linux - 
lfun2_linux
```

But during execution I got the follwing result again:

```
In fun of libfun2_std

In fun of libfun2_std
```

Lets see the content of readelf for libfun2_linux.so

```
 $ readelf -a libfun2_linux.so | grep fun
13: 00000000000006b5    18 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 fun
34: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS libfun2_linux.c
47: 00000000000006b5    18 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 fun
```

Question:-

1. Why having version script for one library is not sufficient as now symbols are different? If we create two version script (one for libfun2_linux.so) it is working fine.
2. How version script works? (Read some links which explain that it works by creatig trees but didnot get it completely). Please suggest some link where it is clearly explained.

Comment: Your question is very confusing and incomplete -- you omit "similar" steps, but details *matter* -- what you linked, in what order, with which options, and what `readelf -Ws` shows for each library matters. I suggest editing the question with *exact* steps, and then saying "I expected to observe X, but observed Y -- where have I gone wrong".